# Straight on the river, how to play it?

Tags: poker-strategy

This was a Cash Game, no limit games ¢1/¢2

Hero ($1.19)
Villain ($4.22)

Hero Small Blind 8♣5♣

Big Blind raise to ¢4 Villain and hero calls.

Flop T⋄2♠4♣

The three players check

Turn 6⋄

The three players check

River 7♥

Hero Bets ¢10 big blind player falls

Villain raises to ¢42

Hero raise again to all in

Sorry for the format I don't know how to put the cards or the hidden texts
[image]

Comment: because you asked me for that :)

Comment: Not what I asked but never mind

Comment: sorry, understood that, but what do you think I should have done?

Comment: I take it this was no-limit hold'em? Other than the loose call pre-flop, it looks ok, but it would be helpful if you would post the amount of the blinds and the action pre-flop. Also, describe the bets in terms of dollars, or your local currency, rather than # of blinds.

Comment: ok will add that

Comment: @HerbWolfe found how to add the cards :) and updated the information, please would love your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your river bet:

You have a strong hand, but this isn't a good spot for a check-raise. Check-calling is a litte too nitty in my opinion. Your bet is fine. I like the sizing.

Facing the villan's raise:

You have the second nuts. It is a really strong hand and you even block 98. Therefore folding is not an option.

I don't think you should re-raise for value. Villan's value raising range is 98, probably 85 and maybe sets, although I really doubt that, since he checked flop and turn. However, to your 4-bet he will likely fold all his sets anyway. Therefore you can't get value if you raise. So that is not an option.

Only one option remains, call. If he has 98, he has 98. It is poker.

Answer (score 2):

You got it all in with a free flop and turn.  It went as well as it could.

If only one hand (89) beats you then you need to call pretty much all the time unless you have a really solid read.

Comment: I lost :P, but I want to feel no regrets :(

Comment: @Saikios Wait, what?  Don't you have the nuts?  There are no flush possibilities as the most of any suit is the two spades...

Comment: @Michael There is a bigger straight.

Comment: Indeed he had a bigger straight  thats why i'm asking if i could prevent it

Comment: You can't prevent it.  Does not mean you should not play it.